# Change user default Git in ssh

Tags: git, authentication, ssh, bitbucket

I have a question related with ssh connection to bitbucket using git protocol.

Is possible to change the default git user when you try to connect to bitbucket server using ssh and a key pair (public and prívate)?

```
Ex: git clone ssh://git@localhost:7999
```

Moreover...

If I set the user with a random user... It works...

Ex:

```
git clone ssh://jfkdlbxj@localhost:7999
```

I would like to audit the access to bitbucket server through ssh...

Thanks a lot.